# How do I position a image to the left and the other image to the center in one line?

Tags: html, css

I am making a login screen but having a hard time finding a solution to view `image 1` on the left side and `image 2` on the center. It always ends up next to each other or the images are on the positions I want but its not in the same line.

```css
img.logo2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
img.roc1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
}
header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="../styles/roc.png" class="roc1">
  <img src="../fts.PNG" class="logo2">
</header>
```

Comment: Try using [align](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGs/att_img_align.asp) attribute!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is doable using `absolute` positioning and `text-align: center`, see this snippet as an example:

```css
img.logo2 {
  display: inline-block;
}
img.roc1 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 250px;
  height: 125px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
header {
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  height: 125px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="../styles/roc.png" class="roc1">
  <img src="../fts.PNG" class="logo2">
</header>
```